# How can I embed my Processing sketch in HTML

Tags: javascript, java, html, processing

I have a problem trying to embed Processing sketch in HTML

Whenever I try using Processing.js I get an empty canvas on my webpage. I think this is because im using elements which doesn't work in JS. I then googled some more and found someone saying "Why don't you add the Processing sketch directly to the webpage" instead of using Processing.js. Problem is: he didn't say how and google doesn't know either as far as I can find. Can someone help? I also found that you can export the sketch and then embed it on website here: http://doc.gold.ac.uk/CreativeComputing/creativecomputation/?page_id=292. Doesn't work either. Do I have to code the applet itself? Still turns out blank...
Here is the basic in my Processing code:

```
void setup() {
  size(600, 600, OPENGL);
  for (int x = -1; x <= 1; x++) {
    for (int y = -1; y <= 1; y++) {
      for (int z = -1; z <= 1; z++) {
        PMatrix3D matrix = new PMatrix3D();
        matrix.translate(x, y, z);
        cube[index] = new Cubie(matrix, x, y, z);
        index++;
      }
    }
  }
}

void draw() {
  //processing-setup-skit, rör inte hur som helst...
  background(51); 
  rotateX(-0.5);
  rotateY(0.4);
  rotateZ(0.1);
  scale(50);

  for (int i = 0; i < cube.length; i++) {
    push();
    if (abs(cube[i].z) > 0 && cube[i].z == currentMove.z) {
      rotateZ(currentMove.angle);
    } else if (abs(cube[i].x) > 0 && cube[i].x == currentMove.x) {
      rotateX(currentMove.angle);
    } else if (abs(cube[i].y) > 0 && cube[i].y == currentMove.y) {
      rotateY(-currentMove.angle);
    }   
    cube[i].show();
    pop();
  }
}
```

I expect to get a canvas which isn't empty although I think cause my Processing code uses java-elements which isn't in JS, it doesn't work. I tried with smaller sketches both 2D and 3D and they all work. If someone is intrested in entire code I'll happily send it over.

How can I embed a "more advanced" sketch in HTML. I've googled everything but can't find anything. Embed .jar, .exe, .pde, anything will do...

Comment: Processing.js was discontinued in December 2018. If you want to do processing-esque things on the web, please have a look at https://p5js.org/ instead

Comment: So converting the processing code to javascript and run with p5.js is the way to go? Thanks man!

Comment: Sort of. It's a bit closer to "redo" your processing sketch in p5js, but your sketch is small so it shouldn't be barely any work.